# jquery ui maps empty markercluster

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have wrote this code to load markers from geojson and put it into markercluster. I'am not able to clear markercluster when the user select something else into dropdown list but clearMarkers() does nothing.

```
var markercluster;
$('#map_tracks').gmap({ 'center': '45.752051,6.295604', 'zoom': 12 }).bind('init', function(ev, map) {
    $('#choose_tracks').change(function() {
    var selected = $('#choose_tracks').val();      

    if ( selected != 'none' )
    {       
        $("#map_tracks").gmap('clear', 'overlays');

        $('#map_tracks').gmap('loadKML', 'sentier', 'http://example.com/media/kml/tracks/'+selected+'.kml');

        $.getJSON( "http://example.com/media/geojson/tracks_poi/"+selected+".geojson").done(function( data ) {
        if ( markercluster != undefined )
        {
            markercluster.clearMarkers();
        }

        $.each( data["features"], function( key, val ) {
            var longitude = val["geometry"]["coordinates"][0];
            var latitude = val["geometry"]["coordinates"][1];
            var nom = val["properties"]["NOM"];
            var type = val["properties"]["TYPE"];

            $('#map_tracks').gmap('addMarker', { 
                  'position': new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                  'icon':'http://example.com/media/kml/sentiers_img_poi/'+markersIcons[type]['name']
              }).click(function() {
                  $('#map_tracks').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': nom }, this);
              });    
      });

      markercluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, $('#map_tracks').gmap('get', 'markers'));

      $('#map_tracks').gmap('set', 'MarkerClusterer', markercluster);  
    });

    drawPath(selected);        
  }   
});    
});
```

How to clear markercluster ?